# Excel VBA - Different methods of declaring variables

Tags: excel, variables, vba

I'm trying to declare 7 variables as Ranges. I'm currently using this format

```
Dim Rg1 As Range
Dim Rg2 As Range
Dim Rg3 As Range
Dim Rg4 As Range
Dim Rg5 As Range
Dim Rg6 As Range
Dim Rg7 As Range
```

But i want to use this format

```
Dim Rg1, Rg2, Rg3, Rg4, Rg5, Rg6, Rg7 As Range
```

I thought there'd be no difference in this but apparently there is. Using the top format, the macro works perfectly. When i change and use the second format, i get the following error

Runtime error '424'
Object Required

It makes this error when the range Rg4 is empty. It doesn't give an error when i use the first format though. Why?

Comment: You are declaring Rg1 through Rg6 as variants not ranges.  The only variable that is being declared a range is the last one.  You can do `Dim Rg1 As Range, Rg2 As Range, ...`

Comment: That is a curious error to get just from changing a variable declaration though. I suspect there is something wrong with your code, such as the omission of a `Set` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring all the values on one line works perfectly with `VB.Net`, but with VBA it is problematic. Thus, declaring `Dim Rg1, Rg4, Rg7 as Range` makes only the last declared value as `Range` and the others are `Variant`.

However, in your case, once you set the other `Rg1` and `Rg4` to ranges, they start acting like a range. E.g., you may ask for `rg4.Address` and you will get it, because the new Type is `Variant/Object/Range` and if you declare it explicitly it will be `Range` - see the VBA monitor for the types:

[image]

Furthermore, once you declare the values as `Variant`, they may change type easily. See the following code, where the types change from `Integer` to `String` once you redeclare it:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim rg1
    Dim rg2
    Dim bornRange   As Range

    Range("A1") = "TEST"

    Debug.Print VarType(rg1) = vbEmpty      'true
    Debug.Print VarType(rg2) = vbEmpty      'true

    Set rg1 = Range("A1")
    rg2 = 2

    Debug.Print VarType(rg1) = vbString     'true
    Debug.Print VarType(rg2) = vbInteger    'true

    Set rg2 = Range("A1")
    Debug.Print rg2.Address                 '$A$1

    Debug.Print VarType(rg2) = vbInteger    'false
    Debug.Print VarType(rg2) = vbString     'true    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you declare your variables this way:

```
Dim Rg1, Rg2, Rg3, Rg4, Rg5, Rg6, Rg7 As Range
```

Only Rg7 will be `Range`, all others variables will be `Variant`
If you want only one line, the only option will be

```
Dim Rg1 As Range, Rg2 As Range, Rg3 As Range, Rg4 As Range, Rg5 As Range, Rg6 As Range, Rg7 As Range
```

Comment: precision: in VB.NET, both lines do the same, while VBA has this dumb behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of ranges, if you'd like:

```
Dim Rng(1 To 7) As Range

Set Rng(1) = ws.Range("A1")
Set Rng(2) = ws.Range("B1")
' Etc....
```

As others have stated, with your declaration:
`Dim Rg1, Rg2, Rg3, Rg4, Rg5, Rg6, Rg7 As Range`
**Rg1-6** are type `Variant`, while **Rg7** is type `Range`